# Error with CoreData Persistent Store

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nspersistentstore

I am working with a CoreData based application and have an AppDelegate class which was inherently written in the launching of the application.

Upon button click, I am passing an ArrayController(Section1) to a subclass and parsing it in order to store TableView Cell values.

```
- (IBAction)saveSect1:(NSButton *)sender {

DataMiner *data = [[DataMiner alloc] init];
[data parseArrayController:Section1 tag:0];


}

-(void)parseArrayController:(NSArrayController *)myController tag:(NSInteger)arrayTag {

switch (arrayTag) {
    case 0:

        context = appDelegate().self.managedObjectContext;

        for (NSMutableDictionary *mydict in myController.arrangedObjects) {

            NSNumberFormatter *format = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
            NSNumber *code = [format numberFromString:[mydict objectForKey:@"diagCode"]];
            [format release];

            Section_1 *section = nil;

            section = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Section_1"   inManagedObjectContext:context];

            section.diagCode = code;
            section.diagDescr = [mydict objectForKey:@"diagDescr"];                            
            section.sectId = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1];
            section.subSectId = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.1];

        }

        NSLog(@"%@", context.registeredObjects);

        [Section_1 release];

        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

}
Initially it ran fine, however, now I receive this error:

**The managed object model version used to open the persistent store is incompatible with the one that was used to create the persistent store.**

Has anyone encountered this error before? Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
if (__managedObjectModel) {
    return __managedObjectModel;
}

NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"CoreData_test"        withExtension:@"momd"];
__managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
return __managedObjectModel;
}
```

Comment: This is one of the first hits on Google for that error, which I think explains it well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572954/error-after-adding-a-new-core-data-model-version

Answer (score 0):

Your table models have changed.  You can either delete the old database (remove the installed app from the device/simulator).  Change the path in the code or do a database migration.

Usually in development I just delete the old install. (In the simulator go to reset content and settings)  If you need to keep the data thats populated then you will need to perform the migration.

You will need to do this anytime you change a table.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, is this for an iOS based application or MacOx? Can you please explain TableModel, as I am working with several ViewController classes which each use a separate NSTableView.I am working with a MacOSX application, and it used the method I added above in the AppDelegate.

Comment: Table Model is probably the wrong term to use...  There is a xcdatamodel file somewhere in your project.  Did you change anything in it after you had already compiled and run the project?  If so then the existing copy of the database for this project is no longer compatible with your file.  You will need to perform a migration or delete the existing install.

Comment: Great thanks, that has worked!

Comment: Glad I could help :) Please vote me up when you can!